# How do you evaluate a set of conditions and create a new column based on a list of columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to take a list (or filter) a set of similarly named columns in a dataframe, evaluate the value for those columns for each row, and then create a new column with the result.

Right now I am using `case_when` but I am not aware of a way to provide some wildcard or list of defined columns.

I would like to take a list, or create a filter, of columns because I want to evaluate several columns in the dataframe, not just a handful. Having a long list of columns in `case_when` seems not efficient when the column names are quite similar to each other.

```
# Dummy data
ignore1 <- c(1, 0, 0)
ignore2 <- c(1, 0, 1)
col1 <- c(0, 1, 0)
col2 <- c(0, 1, 1)
col3 <- c(0, 1, 0)

df <- data.frame(ignore1, ignore2, col1, col2, col3)
```

```
df %>% 
  mutate(evaluation = case_when(
    col1 == 0| col1 == 0 | col1 == 0  ~ "Failed",
    TRUE ~ "Passed"
    )
  )
```

This is the expected result:

```
  ignore1 ignore2 col1 col2 col3 evaluation
1       1       1    0    0    0     Failed
2       0       0    1    1    1     Passed
3       0       1    0    1    0     Failed
```

where row 2 passes because `col1`, `col2`, `col3` *all* have the value of `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `rowSums` to make this efficient

```
i1 <- startsWith(names(df), 'col')
c( "Failed",  "Passed")[(rowSums(df[i1] == 1) == 3) + 1]
#[1] "Failed" "Passed" "Failed"
```

Or another `base R` efficient option is `Reduce`

```
c("Failed", "Passed")[Reduce(`&`, df[i1]) +1]
#[1] "Failed" "Passed" "Failed"
```

NOTE: Both `base R` solutions are compact and are very efficient

---

Or with `&`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     mutate(evaluation =  c('Failed', 'Passed')[1 + (col1 & col2 & col3)])
#  ignore1 ignore2 col1 col2 col3 evaluation
#1       1       1    0    0    0     Failed
#2       0       0    1    1    1     Passed
#3       0       1    0    1    0     Failed
```

Or we can have `rowSums` within `dplyr`

```
df %>%
   mutate(evaluation = c("Failed", "Passed")[(rowSums(.[i1] == 1) == 3) + 1])
```

NOTE: Both the solutions are very efficient and doesn't use any packages that are not really needed

Or if we need some packages, then use `magrittr` with `purrr`

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   mutate(evaluation = select(., starts_with('col')) %>% 
                          reduce(`&`) %>%
                          add(1) %>%
                          c("Failed", "Passed")[.])
#  ignore1 ignore2 col1 col2 col3 evaluation
#1       1       1    0    0    0     Failed
#2       0       0    1    1    1     Passed
#3       0       1    0    1    0     Failed
```

NOTE: Here also, we are not looping over rows, so it should be efficient

Comment: Can you modify your response so that the specific column names or indices are not being referred? Like `col*`?

Comment: @DarenEiri thanks, I changed it to `startsWith` (`i1`).  can you please check if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

As you want to perform a row-wise operation we can use `pmap` variants

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(result =c("Passed","Failed")[pmap_lgl(select(., starts_with('col')),
                       ~any(c(...) == 0)) + 1])

#  ignore1 ignore2 col1 col2 col3 result
#1       1       1    0    0    0 Failed
#2       0       0    1    1    1 Passed
#3       0       1    0    1    0 Failed
```

In base R, we can use `apply` row-wise :

```
cols <- startsWith(names(df), 'col')
df$Result <- c("Passed", "Failed")[apply(df[cols] == 0, 1, any) + 1]
```